# Missing selection set for object GraphQL+Apollo error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a set of mutations that trigger the local state of certain types of popups. They're generally set up like this:

```
  openDialog: (_, variables, { cache }) => {
    const data = {
      popups: {
        ...popups,
        dialog: {
          id: 'dialog',
          __typename: 'Dialog',
          type: variables.type
        }
      }
    };

    cache.writeData({
      data: data
    });
    return null;
  }
```

And the defaults I pass in look like:

```
const defaults = {
  popups: {
    __typename: TYPENAMES.POPUPS,
    id,
    message: null,
    modal: null,
    menu: null,
    dialog: null
  }
};
```

The way they're used in my React code is with a Mutation wrapper component, like so:

```
const OPEN_ALERT_FORM = gql`
  mutation AlertOpenDialog($type: String!) {
    openDialog(type: $type) @client
  }
`;

class Alert extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={OPEN_ALERT_FORM} variables={{ type: ALERT_FORM }}>
        {openDialog => {
          return (
            <Button
              classes="alert-button"
              onClick={openDialog}
              label="Trigger Alert"
            />
          );
        }}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```

For my various popups (I have 3 or 4 different ones, like `menu` and `modal`), the mutations to open and close them all look the same, just different typenames and content etc. But, for Dialogs, I get this error when I click on them:

*Network error: Missing selection set for object of type Dialog returned for query field dialog*

...and then the triggering component disappears from the page. Plus, once that happens, all other popup types disappear when you try clicking on them, and either re-throw that error, or say:

*Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.*

I've tried re-writing dialogs to match up with other popup types, and re-writing the components as well, but I'm still getting this error. It does appear to be dialog+Apollo specific.
What could be the root of this issue? It can't be a backend thing, because this is only dealing with local Apollo. I haven't seen this error before and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What does the `defaults` object you pass to `withClientState` look like?

Comment: @DanielRearden just updated question with the defaults!

Comment: Hmm. It looks like that error gets thrown whenever the cache has some object (as opposed to just a scalar value) and you try to read that object from the cache without specifying a selection set (i.e. which fields on the type). You can take a look at the test [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory/src/__tests__/diffAgainstStore.ts#L975). Do you have a query that requests the `dialog` field on `popups` without specifying the fields on `dialog`?

Comment: i.e. something like `query { popups { dialog } }` ?

Comment: @DanielRearden I'll check that out, thanks! I do have a query that checks that, and it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: If you do have a query that's missing a selection set like that one, I suspect it's working when your cached value is null (i.e. the default), but then breaks once you populate the cache with a mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this turned out to work by treating the `dialog` field as a string instead of an object. Changing the function to this did the trick and made the errors go away:

```
  openDialog: (_, variables, { cache }) => {
    const data = {
      popups: {
        ...popups,
        dialog: variables.type
      }
    };

    cache.writeData({
      data: data
    });
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: well it does not solve the original question but rather changing data model to avoid the error. You're lucky being free to alter the model ;)

Answer (score 15):

Solution is to add fields to the query (vs. declaring the top-level object you want to fetch without specifying the fields to fetch). If you have something like:

```
{
  popups @client {
    id
    dialog
  }
}
```

you must declare some fields to fetch inside `dialog`, for example `id`:

```
{
  popups @client {
    id
    dialog {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the actual problem seems lay in the query. Initially Apollo client was not validating types for `@client` queries/mutations so your mutation could look like you wrote it in the question:

```
mutation AlertOpenDialog($type: String!) {
  openDialog(type: $type) @client
}
```

the correct way of writing above is to specify (select) all the simple type (scalar) fields you wanna get in a response. So in regard to the @Vic answer the mutation should look more like:

```
mutation AlertOpenDialog($type: String!) {
  openDialog(type: $type) @client {
    dialog {
      id
    }
  }
}
```