# Missing selection set for object of type X returned for query field Y

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-tools

I'm relatively new to GraphQL.  I have a query like so:

```
 query messages ($assetId: ID!) {
    messages (assetId: $assetId, offset: 0, limit: 3) {
      id
      text
      time
      sender {
        ...on Asset {
          id
          name
        }
        ...on Contact {
          id
          name
        }
      }
      conversation {
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

which, when executed via a react-apollo `<Query />` component, gives the error:

> Network error: Missing selection set for object of type Asset returned for query field sender

I have no idea why this would be considered a "Network error".

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265804/1136527), the "Missing Selection set" refers to the fields requested inside a nested object, which would make sense except I'm clearly including fields on type "Asset" in the query above.

Removing the `sender` fields such that the query looks like this:

```
 query messages ($assetId: ID!) {
    messages (assetId: $assetId, offset: 0, limit: 3) {
      id
      text
      time
      sender
      conversation {
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

changes the error to

> Network error: Missing selection set for object of type Conversation returned for query field conversation

and removing the fields from `conversation`, the query runs fine (although `{}` is returned for all `sender`/`conversation`s).

Because the error moves to `conversation` when I effectively skip `sender`, I think this is unrelated to `sender` being a Union-type.

I am running this query against an executable schema (via [`makeExectuableSchema`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema/)) with types:

```
type Asset {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Contact {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

union ConversationMember = Asset | Contact

type Message {
  id: ID!
  sender: ConversationMember!
  conversation: Conversation!
  time: Time!
  text: String!
}

type Conversation {
  id: ID!
  members: [ConversationMember!]!
  messages: [Message!]!
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something obvious?  I can't seem to explain this error in this situation.

Edit:

I am using apollo-boost and creating a client like so:

```
export default new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    fragmentMatcher: new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
      introspectionQueryResultData: introspectionResult
    })
  }),
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema })
}));
```

Because `union` types require an `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher`, I have to introspect the schema to get types.  Hence, I am creating a cache like so:

```
const query = gql`
  query {
    __schema {
      types {
        kind
        name
        possibleTypes {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

...

return new InMemoryCache({
  fragmentMatcher: new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
    introspectionQueryResultData: response.data
   })
});
```

Interestingly, inspecting the result of the schema query, I see that everything has a `__typename` of `"__Type"`:

```
{kind: "OBJECT", name: "Query", possibleTypes: null, __typename: "__Type"},
{kind: "OBJECT", name: "Asset", possibleTypes: null, __typename: "__Type"},
{kind: "OBJECT", name: "Contact", possibleTypes: null, __typename: "__Type"},
{kind: "OBJECT", name: "Conversation", possibleTypes: null, __typename: "__Type"},
{kind: "UNION", name: "ConversationMember", possibleTypes: Array(2), __typename: "__Type"},
{kind: "OBJECT", name: "Message", possibleTypes: null, __typename: "__Type"}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your client config?

Comment: That error generally indicates something is wrong with your cache. I believe that can happen under at least two circumstances: 1) you write directly to the cache incorrectly or 2) you've got a `dataIdFromObject` function that's funky. I imagine setting `addTypename` to `false` may also cause similar problems.

Comment: I wonder if `SchemaLink` is the culprit here. I've only played around once with that link before, but my understanding is that it should be used in an SSR context. Is this an SSR app?

Comment: No, it's not SSR.  I'm trying to get a mocked instance available for development purposes, at this stage just from a copy of our `.graphql` schema file.

Comment: I would try swapping in a regular HttpLink and see if you still see the same issue. Also, I just noticed you said you were using Apollo Boost... I was under the impression that Apollo Boost did not accept `link` as a configuration option and that it expected the fragmentMatcher to be passed directly to its constructor (documentation for Boost kind of sucks but you can check [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-boost/src/index.ts#L29))

Comment: The difficulty is that I don't have a server running for development, hence no URI for an `HttpLink` to hit... Interesting about Boost - AFAICT you need the frag matcher to create the cache, which is also an arg to Boost.  Do I need to provide both?

Comment: Not 100% sure. I never use Boost because most projects quickly outgrow it and I don't see any benefit to it. If you're already providing both a link and cache, you might as well just [migrate to using the full client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration/). Even if that doesn't resolve this particular issue, it's still a good thing to do.

Comment: Side note, if you've already got a GraphQLSchema (which is what you're passing to `SchemaLink`, it's trivial to just spin up an ApolloServer instance locally. You can pass it the schema directly in lieu of resolvers/typeDefs. Then you'll have a URI for your HttpLink.